# XML replace invalid characters (allowed list)

Tags: xml, list, powershell, character

I have an input XML file (comes from another server) which contains a `<Notes>` node that has all the user inputted comments. Being free form text it can contain all sorts of weird characters. What I would like to do is to strip out all characters except for an allowed list which would be

- a-z (lowercase)
- A-Z (uppercase)
- Other normal characters e.g. (space, _,!?./;:<>(){}/[]"')

The source XML looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrganisationUnits>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="1">
    <OrganisationId>PROV1</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>PROVIDER 1</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
    </Addresses>
    <ContactDetails>
      <ContactDetailsRow num="1">
        <Notes>0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</Notes>
      </ContactDetailsRow>
    </ContactDetails>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="2">
    <OrganisationId>PROV2</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>PROVIDER 2</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="1">
        <AddressId>G72516</AddressId>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
    <ContactDetails>
      <ContactDetailsRow num="1">
        <Notes>0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</Notes>
      </ContactDetailsRow>
    </ContactDetails>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
</OrganisationUnits>
```

My code is finding the right part of the XML document but it is not performing the replace.

```bsh
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path\$xml_out)
$AcceptedChars = '[^a-z0-9 _,!?./;:<>(){}\[\]''\-\\"]'
$ReplaceChars = ""

foreach ($ContactDetailsRow in $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.ContactDetails) {
    $n = $ContactDetailsRow.Item('Notes')
    Write-Host "found the notes node `$n"
    #check if the provider has got a notes node
    if ($n) {
        #do the search/replace
        if ($n -NotMatch $AcceptedChars) {
            $n -replace $AcceptedChars, $ReplaceChars
        }
    }
}
$xml.Save("$path\$xml_out")
```

I'm trying to use a regex replace to do the work but it's not happening for me.

Code changed as per Ansgar's comment and simplified the AllowedChars to just numerics to show that it isn't working:

```bsh
$path = "C:\TEST"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path\source.xml)
$xmlout = "$path\new.xml"

$AcceptedChars = "a-z"
$InvalidChars  = '[^{0}]' -f [regex]::Escape($AcceptedChars)
$ReplaceChar   = '_'

foreach ($ContactDetailsRow in $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.ContactDetails) {
    $n = $ContactDetailsRow.Item('Notes')

    if ($n.'#text' -match $InvalidChars) {
        $n.'#text' = $n.'#text' -replace $InvalidChars, $ReplaceChar
    } else {
        #There is no match on the accepted characters
        echo "NO MATCH - we have not made a match on invalid characters"
    }
}
$xml.Save($xmlout)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is broken. You named the variable `$AcceptedChars` and use it as if it contained the accepted characters (`-notmatch $AcceptedChars`), but it's actually defined as the characters that are not accepted (`[^...]`). A caret at the beginning of a character class inverts the class (match anything but these characters). Also, you need to check the `#text` property of the node, not the node object itself:

```
$AcceptedChars = "a-z0-9 _,!?./;:<>(){}[]'`"-\"
$InvalidChars  = '[^{0}]' -f [regex]::Escape($AcceptedChars)
$ReplaceChar   = '_'   # it's usually safer to replace invalid characters with
                       # a safe character rather than flat out remove them
...
if ($n.'#text' -match $InvalidChars) {
    $n.'#text' = $n.'#text' -replace $InvalidChars, $ReplaceChar
}
```

With that said, the XML sample from your question can't even be parsed as XML, because it contains an unencoded ampersand. Hence your code will already fail in the first line:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path\$xml_out)
```

with an error like this:

> Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 15, position 31."

So you may need to do something like this first:

```
$xmlfile = Join-Path $path $xml_out
(Get-Content $xmlfile) -replace '&', '&amp;' | Set-Content $xmlfile
```

Or like this:

```
$xmlfile = Join-Path $path $xml_out
[xml]$xml = (Get-Content $xmlfile) -replace '&', '&amp;'
```

Comment: If we ignore the & in the source xml file (I can fix that separately as you said), I still can't get the replace to work. 
If the source xml is simplified like this to contain just numerics and alphas and the AcceptedChars is set to "a-z" it wont find a match.

Comment: `$n = $ContactDetailsRow.Item('Notes')` -> `$n = $ContactDetailsRow.ContactDetailsRow.Notes`. Just because you name the loop variable `$ContactDetailsRow` doesn't magically put the child node `<ContactDetailsRow>` in it. Better yet, simply use `foreach ($n in $xml.SelectNodes('//Notes'))`.

Comment: Hi Ansgar - now working perfectly, I simply forgot to write out the new values back to the xml file - doh.